# Maximizing value using shooting method

Tags: c, optimization, maximize

I have a nonlinear equation that uses an initial y'(a) and outputs a value y(b) such that y(b)=f(y'(a)), where f(x) is some function. The idea is that I'd like to be able to maximize y(b).

Typically, if I had a value for y(b), I could use the shooting or secant method. However I don't have that value. I was thinking I could use a loop to find the max value, but that is very inefficient. Anything better I could use?

*Edit: Also I do not have an explicit expression for f(x).

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Brent minimization method seems applicable here, provided that y'(a) is just a number (and not a whole vector)

Comment: See eg. https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Minimization-Algorithms.html